# Symfony 3.3 doctrine SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2013

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

The query below is blocking the shared host with error

> ```
> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2013 Lost connection to MySQL server during query
> ```

This query is a Symfony/Doctrine's version of way bigger query using plain PHP that I am moving over Symfony/Doctrine. I already sliced and diced it to 8 smaller queries, but still facing same issue.

Note that the original, enormous query, runs on the same shared host without a hitch.

php.ini max_execution_time is set to 60,which should be way more than enough.

Also note that on my local server this query clocks at around 1 ms, as per Symfony's profiler. This is very much on the same range as the other 7 similar queries.

The WHERE and GROUP BY clauses is the same for all the said 8 queries, so that should not be the issue.

Any ideas?

```
        $query = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery(
            "SELECT v.id AS version_id,
            pr.price AS price,
            mt.power AS mpower,
            ms.trunk AS trunk
            FROM AppBundle:Version v
            JOIN v.prices pr
            JOIN v.motor mt
            JOIN v.measure ms
            WHERE v.id IN (:version_ids)
            GROUP BY v.id
            ORDER BY pr.price"
        )
        ->setParameter('version_ids', $version_ids);
```

A summary of the entities is like:

/src/AppBundle/Entity/Version.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\VersionRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="versions")
 */
class Version
{
/**
 * @var integer
 * 
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="smallint",length=4,unique=true,options={"unsigned":true})
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

.....

/**
 * Many versions have One motor.
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Motor")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="motor_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $motor;

/**
 * Many versions have One set of measures.
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Measure")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="measure_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $measure;
...
```

/src/AppBundle/Entity/Price.php

```
class Price
{

/** 
* @ORM\Id 
* @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Version", inversedBy="prices") 
*/
private $version;
...
```

/src/AppBundle/Entity/Measure.php

```
class Measure
{
/**
 * @var integer
 * 
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="smallint",length=4,unique=true,options={"unsigned":true})
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;
...
```

/src/AppBundle/Entity/Motor.php

```
class Motor
{
/**
 * @var integer
 * 
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="smallint",length=4,unique=true,options={"unsigned":true})
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;
....
```

EDIT: EXPLAIN SELECT result:

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys       key      key_len    ref           rows    Extra     
1   SIMPLE         v0_      range   PRIMARY,UNIQ_,IDX_1 PRIMARY  2          NULL            5     Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE         p1_      eq_ref  PRIMARY             PRIMARY  2          v0_.id          1     NULL
1   SIMPLE         m2_      eq_ref  PRIMARY,UNIQ_       PRIMARY  2          v0_.motor_id    1     NULL
1   SIMPLE         m3_      eq_ref  PRIMARY,UNIQ_       PRIMARY  2          v0_.measure_id  1     NULL
```

SHOW WARNINGS just comes back with a Level = Note and Code = 1003 which should just be the regular EXPLAIN EXTENDED code, as far as I understand.

Comment: You could let Doctrine display the generated SQL with `$this->getEntityManager()->createQuery()->getSQL();` and try running it against the MySQL server from the command line. Of course, Doctrine will give you one of its unreadable SQL queries, but even running that against the server and maybe poking a bit around with `EXPLAIN SELECT` or `SHOW WARNINGS` might help you. Or try modifying the query to see if you can isolate the problem.

Comment: Since you mentioned that was a shared host, could it be that you mysql connection are limited in resource consumption (e.g. how much RAM can it take)? 

What is the order of magnitude of resultset count?

Comment: @JovanPerovic. There's always a limit and, being a shared host, the limit is certainly not that high. The question is why it allows a much complex query coming from plain PHP to execute but blocks a comparatively way simpler query produced by Doctrine? Is there something inherently inefficient on that query or the underlying table configuration? Should not be the latter as the tables' structures are identical.

Comment: It could be the hydration, although there is no ToMany relation joined. How many are the version_ids?

Comment: versions  and prices tables have about 2000 lines, while measures and motors are below 1000 lines

Comment: @lxg, thanks, I added the SELECT EXPLAIN and SHOW WARNINGS output to my question. Nothing strikes me as unusual, but may be I am missing something.

Comment: Try to limit your results eg "$query->setMaxResults(100);" Do you still get the error?